# IntelliJ not detecting unshaded source files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

I have a maven module which shades `guice-persist` (the actual artefact and change are irrelevant). To do this we have a module named the same but with an added suffix, e.g. `guice-persist-mycompany`. The module in my project replicates the package structure so that when we run the shade plugin it will essentially replace the original file with our modified one. This works when doing a `mvn clean install` or similar.

The problem I have is that IntelliJ can't resolve classes within `guice-persist` that are *not* present in my project (i.e. everything other than `ModifiedClass.java`). This is especially painful when trying to run unit tests with coverage, and I usually give up and use the command line (and/or remote test debugging).

I have been able to resolve the issue by adding the `guice-persist` dependency from .m2 (manually) in the module settings for the `guice-persist-mycompany`, but this means each developer has to do the same.

How can I can modify the `pom.xml` for my module `guice-persist-mycompany` to give IntelliJ a hint for where to find the source files that are not shaded?